# Create Team Project in TFS2015 in Team Web Access without Visual Studio?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I would like to know if there is a possibility to create a team project in TFS2015!! in the Web Interface without using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

This is due to TFS's capability to interface with SharePoint and Reporting Services.

Update: This is now possible in TFS 2015 Update 2 (however, there is a limitation that it won't create an associated SharePoint portal or SSRS reports).

Comment: That's correct. We are working on making team project creation work in TFS from the web for an update of TFS 2015 with the limitation that it won't set up SharePoint and Reporting Services.

Comment: @BuckHodges It does not seem to be added to update 1, or does it?

Comment: It is not in Update 1. It's now on the list in our feature timeline (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso).